# Remix Tutorial for latest version

Tags: solidity, remix

I am finding online tutorials for Remix/Solidity but issue is that Remix is totally changed and I am clueless how to even run a simple contract. Is there any latest updated tutorial or documents? Below is screenshot of my simple contract and I have no idea how to *Run* it.

[image]

Comment: It looks like you've created your contract successfully. (The pink `Create` button.) There are buttons equating to each of your contract's functions at the bottom. Click them (and provide arguments where appropriate) to run the those functions. In the grey window under the contract code, you'll be returned the associated transaction. Click the `Details` button to see the transaction contents.

Answer (score 1):

It'll be hard to find up-to-date tutorials with all of the latest tools because updates happen early and often. Most tools are actually still in the beta phase (or not even at the 1.0 version phase) and best practices are still being debated.

Comment: How to run the current program?